# Accessibility accessibilityDecrement() not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, accessibility

Why are not accessibilityDecrement() and accessibilityIncrement() getting called in my custom UITextView when performing the appropriate gestures?

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView  {

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      accessibilityTraits = accessibilityTraits | UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable
   }

   override func accessibilityDecrement() {
      print("Decrement")
   }

   override func accessibilityIncrement() {
      print("Increment")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
isAccessibilityElement = true

accessibilityTraits = super.accessibilityTraits | UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable
```

Comment: UITextView already has isAccessibilityElement set to true. Since I have not overriden the variable accessibilityTraits calling super.accessibilityTraits is the same as just calling accessibilityTraits---the result is the same. Just to make sure, I did try out your suggestions: no difference, the accessibilityDecrement/Increment methods are still not beeing called.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Turns out I had forgotten that I was setting textView.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText in the ViewController.viewDidLoad. Duhh...